# HowTo configure phpMyAdmin to show specific databases only for root user

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed phpMyAdmin 4 on Ubuntu 14.04 with access for multiple users.
This works fine but I am wondering how to hide specific databases for all users except root.

For all users I edited /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(information_schema|mysql)$';
```

And how to configure phpMyAdmin to show this databases only for root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the database, I would recommend removing their access via the Users menu.  Typically you should only allow users access to the tables they need access to; hiding a database would not prevent them from dropping a hidden table or even changing the root password via a SQL statement if they still have access to the users table.